# PLSQL- How to exit FORALL Loop

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g

I have the following code snippet in a procedure, currently 
`apps.fnd_global. apps_initialize` method execution is part of  FORALL loop.

I would like to call `apps.fnd_global. apps_initialize` not in the loop. When insert finishes, then `apps.fnd_global. apps_initialize` should execute only once.

How can I do this?

```
FORALL i IN 1 .. my_array.COUNT
         INSERT
           INTO my_table
            ......
      COMMIT;         

         apps.fnd_request.submit_request (application   => 'PO',
                                          program       => 'REQIMPORT',
                                          argument1     => l_p4,
                                          argument2     => l_p5,
                                          argument3     => l_p6,
                                          argument4     => '',
                                          argument5     => 'N',
                                          argument6     => 'N');
      COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try by loop:-

```
FOR i IN 1 .. my_array.COUNT
   LOOP
       INSERT
       INTO my_table
        ......
   END LOOP;
   commit;      

     apps.fnd_request.submit_request (application   => 'PO',
                                      program       => 'REQIMPORT',
                                      argument1     => l_p4,
                                      argument2     => l_p5,
                                      argument3     => l_p6,
                                      argument4     => '',
                                      argument5     => 'N',
                                      argument6     => 'N');
```

Comment: Yes FORALL cannot be clubbed with any business logic . Here in your case you are calling procedure inside it. Try to use FOR loop as mentioned in the answer. Only DML'S are allowed

Comment: Do note though: a `forall` loop executes a statement `N` (N = `my_array.count`) number of times inside the SQL engine, making it a very fast, single, SQL statement, while a `for` loop is a PLSQL loop, resulting in `N` context switches back and forth between the PLSQL engine and the SQL engine. If `N` is sufficiently large, this will have a noticable delay. It might even be more efficient to first use `forall` to insert all the data, and then use a separate for loop to do the post-processing. For, say, 100 or 1000 rows this won't be a problem, though.

Comment: @GolezTrol You mean to say for 100 to 1000 rows `FORALL` or `for loop` doesn't make any difference?

Comment: It does make a difference, but 100 rows will be pretty fast with all the context switches too. It's not always necessary to optimize such a loop, but if you can use a forall without reducing the readability or maintanebility of your code, it's usually a good idea. If you need to split the logic into separate loops it's a grey area and a matter of opinion which is best: more readable code or slightly faster code. That's up to you.

Answer (score 6):

FORALL is not a loop - so you cannot exit the loop.  If you want to limit the work that FORALL performs then you need to limit the data returned from the original BULK COLLECT.

FND_GLOBAL.apps_initialize() sets session-level globals.  You can call it before your FORALL clause (if you want your insert to use the new global values) or after (if you only want to affect the concurrent program execution).